# Angular2: input checkbox with label doesn't work in table

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to create table with independent checkboxes in one of the columns. The button is styled as [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch) (it forces input inside label). My problem is that it doesn't change states when is located in table. (Beyond table works ok)

```
<table>

    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Check</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
       <td>
         <label class="switch">
           <input type="checkbox" (click)="changed($event)">
           <div class="slider"></div>
         </label>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

I also tried to add specific id to each input but without success.

Comment: This code is not saying very much unfortunately. What are you doing on `changed` method?

Comment: Nothing big yet, just log to check if changed($event) is called

Comment: could you try setting a different id AND name to each input?

Comment: I've tried too, with different id and different name

Comment: It would be interesting if you can share an example on plunker on any other collaborative web tool. Your code is very simple, I don't see how it can't fail

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>

<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Check</th>
   </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
   <td>
     <label class="switch">
       <input type="checkbox" (change)="changed($event)" >

       <input type="checkbox" (change)="changed($event, item)" [checked]="item.checkbox">
       <div class="slider"></div>
     </label>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```